# Git refuses to track some files (git add -f not working)

Tags: git

I must probably have unknowingly mispunched some keys and triggered a strange change in the state of my local git repository, for now git is refusing to track some files. That is :

If I do `git add -f myfile.txt`, it executes and returns silently but after that `git ls-files -v myfile.txt` still returns  nothing when it should return `myfile.txt`, and `git status` still says `nothing to commit`.

Someone suggested that problem might have to do with some filenames being too long, so I tried `git config core.longpaths true` followed by `git add .` and `git add -A`.

And yes, I did check that the file exists and the path is correct : `file myfile.txt` tells me it's an ASCII text.

What other git commands may I use to get a better understanding of the situation ?

UPDATE : In the output of `git ls-tree -r HEAD`, my file is listed , albeit with a slight modification : what I called `myfile.txt` above for short is really a long file path with several directories. The corresponding entry in `git ls-tree -r HEAD` is an identical path except that the first directory is uncapitalized (I and the Unix system call it `Depth_one` but git calls it `depth_one`).

Comment: I would first think that the file is indeed not change and, if that is not the case, then probably it's been configured to be skipped with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`. What does `git ls-files -v` tell you about the file? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: @eftshift0 `git ls-files -v myfile.txt` does the same thing as `git ls-files  myfile.txt` without the `-v`, i.e. it does not return anything and exits silently.

Comment: @eftshift0 I don't quite get your point about the file not being changed. It is indeed unchanged since the last commit, but this is not a reason for this file to stop being tracked, so the (empty) output of `git ls-files` is still wrong.

Comment: Is the file listed in `git ls-tree -r HEAD`?

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks for this suggestion, I've just appended the info provided by `git ls-tree -r HEAD` at the end of my question, please see above

Comment: Ok..... this is interesting because then git _might_ be thinking that the file is not really tracked in a very twisted way?

Comment: @eftshift0 Indeed, this looks so twisted that I have no idea how to proceed further with the debugging

Comment: What happens if you rename the directory to what git expects it to be?

Comment: Do you have submodules? Do you have another `.git` directory inside one of your folders?

Comment: @eftshift0 If I rename the directory to the uncapitalized version, then `git ls-files` sees the file again. It looks like a "capitalization of names in git on a Mac", at the moment I'm reading https://izziswift.com/i-change-the-capitalization-of-a-directory-and-git-doesnt-seem-to-pick-up-on-it/

Comment: @knittl I don't have submodules, if there's another .git subdirectory it's an unintended accident

Comment: i am glad you have a _kind of_ explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR summary: the root issue here is case-folding.  You may wish to convince Git to rename all the files.  (Files in Git's index, AKA staging area, are not in *folders*, they just have *long names that seem to have folder-names embedded within them*.  The names you need to change are therefore all the ones that start with the lowercase "folder" string.)  Alternatively, make your working tree match the Git commits: in Git, file names *are* case sensitive.

#### Long, with reproducible example

> UPDATE : In the output of `git ls-tree -r HEAD`, my file is listed , albeit with a slight modification : what I called `myfile.txt` above for short is really a long file path with several directories. The corresponding entry in `git ls-tree -r HEAD` is an identical path except that the first directory is uncapitalized (I and the Unix system call it `Depth_one` but git calls it `depth_one`).

This, and the fact that you are on macOS—or at a lower level, using a case-insensitive file system—are the key items.  I was able to reproduce your issue on my own Mac, although perhaps with a slightly different reproducer.  (This sort of thing is why a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is so important here.  Simplifying a problem to its nub is good, but simplifying it to the point where it's *gone* is no help at all!)

To reproduce the problem, I ran:

```
sh-3.2$ cd ~/tmp
sh-3.2$ mkdir gitpath && cd gitpath && git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/torek/tmp/gitpath/.git/
sh-3.2$ mkdir -p depth_one/depth_two
sh-3.2$ touch depth_one/f1.txt depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
sh-3.2$ git add .
sh-3.2$ git commit -m initial -m "" -m "commit with all lowercase names"
[master (root-commit) 5462107] initial
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
 create mode 100644 depth_one/f1.txt
sh-3.2$
```

Next, we *remove and then re-create the `depth_one` directory without telling Git about it*, like so:

```
sh-3.2$ rm -r depth_one
sh-3.2$ mkdir Depth_one
sh-3.2$ git status -s
sh-3.2$ git status -s
 D depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
 D depth_one/f1.txt
```

These `D` status-es show that the files have gone missing, which is true.  We can get them back with `git checkout`, extracting them from Git's index:

```
sh-3.2$ git checkout -- .
sh-3.2$ git status -s
```

It's useful to see what Git thinks is in the index / staging-area at this point:

```
sh-3.2$ git ls-files --stage
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0   depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0   depth_one/f1.txt
```

The hash IDs here are those of the empty blob.  Let's put some data in the working tree copies, under their new names `Depth_one/f1.txt` and `Depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt`:

```
sh-3.2$ echo data for file one > Depth_one/f1.txt 
sh-3.2$ echo different data for file two > Depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
sh-3.2$ git status -s
 M depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
 M depth_one/f1.txt
```

Now we put some data in the two files, `f1.txt` and `f2.txt`, in the renamed directory in the working tree.  Git still believes that the names are all lowercase, and because the default file system that I am using here does case-folding, Git's attempts to work with files named `depth_one/f1.txt` and `depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt` accesses the files whose names now begin with `Depth_one` in the actual working tree.

```
sh-3.2$ echo data for file one > Depth_one/f1.txt 
sh-3.2$ echo different data for file two > Depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt 
sh-3.2$ git status -s
 M depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
 M depth_one/f1.txt
```

The short status shows that the working tree copies are modified, but an explicit `git add` of each *file* has no effect:

```
sh-3.2$ git add Depth_one/f1.txt Depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
sh-3.2$ git status -s
 M depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
 M depth_one/f1.txt
```

Running `git add Depth_one/` has the same lack of effect.  Interestingly, however, `git add .` is different:

```
sh-3.2$ git add .
sh-3.2$ git status -s
M  depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
M  depth_one/f1.txt
sh-3.2$ git ls-files --stage
100644 ee13bb89375a5217f36cb6ee6573fcd05b1719ca 0   depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
100644 bb5f31937e0c394dabee30155dab5d3f23a4c5c3 0   depth_one/f1.txt
```

Note that the full file names are still all-lowercase.  To convince Git to pick up the changed names, it suffices to remove the index entries and then re-create them from scratch:

```
sh-3.2$ git rm --cached -r .
rm 'depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt'
rm 'depth_one/f1.txt'
sh-3.2$ git add .
sh-3.2$ git ls-files --stage
100644 ee13bb89375a5217f36cb6ee6573fcd05b1719ca 0   Depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
100644 bb5f31937e0c394dabee30155dab5d3f23a4c5c3 0   Depth_one/f1.txt
sh-3.2$ git status -s
A  Depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
A  Depth_one/f1.txt
D  depth_one/depth_two/f2.txt
D  depth_one/f1.txt
```

(there are no renames detected here because the old files are empty and the new ones are much too different from the empty old ones; but if the files had actual contents, Git would show these as renames).

(All testing was with Git 2.20.1; I have not updated the Git on this Mac in quite a while.)